# If $X \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ is a set bounded then $\forall a\in R^n,$ $X\subset B[a,r]$.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

I need to know whether the proposition is properly demonstrated. But first consider the following:

**Definition.** A set $X \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ is bounded if and only if there exists $c\in \mathbb{R}$ with $c>0$ such that $\Vert x\Vert<c$ (where $\Vert\cdot\Vert$ is the Euclidean norm, the maximum, or the sum in $\mathbb{R}^n$).

**Proposition.**
Let $X\subset R^n$ a bounded set, then: 
$\forall a\in\mathbb{R}^n$ there is a real number $r>0$ such that $X\subset B[a,r]=\{x\in \mathbb{R}^n \;|\; ||x-a||\leq r\}.$

*Demonstration:*
Let $x\in X$ and $a\in \mathbb{R}^n$ then:
$$\Vert x\Vert = \Vert x-a+a\Vert \leq \Vert x-a\Vert+\Vert a\Vert,\tag{1} $$
then as $X$ is bounded we can find a $c\in \Bbb R$ sufficiently large such that:
 $$ \Vert x\Vert \leq \Vert x-a\Vert+\Vert a\Vert \leq c. \tag2 $$
So
 $$ \Vert x-a\Vert \leq c- \Vert a\Vert\tag3 $$
Now choose $r=c-\Vert a\Vert$ with $c$ such that $r>0$, then:
 $$ \Vert x-a\Vert \leq r. \tag4 $$
This implies $x\in B[a,r]$. Consequently, if $x\in X$ then $x\in B[a,r]$.

Therefore, $$X\subset B[a,r].$$

---

I have great doubt about the inequality in $(2)$. I am very grateful for your views.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right to have some doubts about the inequality $(2)$. Why?

What you know is as you said that there exists $c>0$ such that for all $x \in X$, $\Vert x \Vert \le c$. Then you can not be sure that $c$ is also larger than $\Vert x-a\Vert+\Vert a\Vert$.

However, you were having good ideas. You can use reverse triangle inequality $$\vert \Vert z \Vert - \Vert y \Vert \vert \le \Vert z-y \Vert$$ taking for $z$, $x-a$ and for $y$, $-a$. Doing that you get $$\vert \Vert x-a \Vert - \Vert a \Vert \vert \le \Vert x \Vert$$ hence $$\Vert x-a \Vert - \Vert a \Vert \le \Vert x \Vert$$

Then you can conclude $$\Vert x-a \Vert \le \Vert x \Vert + \Vert a \Vert \le c +\Vert a \Vert$$ for any $x \in X$.

Comment: many thanks!! is perfect.

Comment: This only shows $\Vert x-a\Vert+\Vert a\Vert\leq c+2\Vert a\Vert$...which is trivial by the triangle inequality (see my post). Also, note that the definition and the proof are separate, so what you have done is demonstrate a $\tilde c\in\Bbb R$ large enough so that $\Vert x-a\Vert+\Vert a\Vert\leq\tilde c$...

Comment: @Clayton I don't understand your comment. What I proved in the lines above is that $X \subset B(a,r)$ where $a$  is any point of $\mathbb R^n$ and $r =c+\Vert a \Vert$... which was the question of the OP.

Answer (score 1):

For the inequality in $(2)$, just note that since $X$ is a bounded, we have $$\Vert x\Vert<c$$ for all $x\in X$ and some $c\in\Bbb R$. Now, for any fixed $a\in\Bbb R^n$, we have $$\Vert x\Vert\leq\Vert x-a\Vert+\Vert a\Vert \leq\Vert x\Vert + 2\Vert a\Vert\leq\underbrace{c+2\Vert a\Vert}_\tilde{c}.$$ Now follow through the proof with $\tilde{c}$.

Comment: It seems reasonable, I will continue analyzing.

Comment: @mathsalomon: No problem. If you have questions, feel free to ask.